# Having problems panning and zooming data received by d3.json in a line chart

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to build this trend component that is able to zoom and pan in data fetched with d3.json. First off, here's my code:

```
<script>

    var margin = { top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 20, left: 50 },
        width = $("#trendcontainer").width() - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
    var x = d3.time.scale()
        .domain([-width / 2, width / 2])
        .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([-height / 2, height / 2])
        .range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.category10();
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .tickSize(-height);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(5)
        .tickSize(-width);

    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .x(x)
        .y(y)
        .scaleExtent([1, 10])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);

    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate("basis")
        .x(function(d) {
            return x(d.date);
        })
        .y(function(d) {
            return y(d.value);
        });

    var svg = d3.select(".panel-body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .call(zoom);

    d3.json('@Url.Action("DataBlob", "Trend", new {id = Model.Unit.UnitId, runId = 5})', function(error, json) {
        $('#processing').hide();
        color.domain(d3.keys(json[0]).filter(function(key) {
            return key !== "Time" && key !== "Id";
        }));

        data.forEach(function(d) { var date = new Date(parseInt(d.Time.substr(6))); d.Time = date; });

        var instruments = color.domain().map(function(name) {
            return {
                name: name,
                values: data.map(function(d) {
                    return {
                        date: d.Time,
                        value: +d[name]
                    };
                })
            };
        });

        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Time; }));
        y.domain([
            d3.min(instruments, function(c) {
                return d3.min(c.values, function(v) {
                    return v.value;
                });
            }),
            d3.max(instruments, function(c) {
                return d3.max(c.values, function(v) {
                    return v.value;
                });
            })
        ]);

        svg.append("rect")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis);

        var instrument = svg.selectAll(".instrument")
            .data(instruments)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "instrument");

        instrument.append("path")
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", function(d) {
                return line(d.values);
            })
            .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

        instrument.append("text")
            .datum(function(d) {
                return {
                    name: d.name,
                    value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
                };
            })
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.value) + ")"; })
            .attr("x", 3)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
    });

    function zoomed() {
        svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
        svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
        svg.select(".x.grid")
            .call(make_x_axis()
                .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
                .tickFormat(""));
        svg.select(".y.grid")
            .call(make_y_axis()
                .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
                .tickFormat(""));
        svg.select(".line")
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", line);
    };

    var make_x_axis = function() {
        return d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom")
            .ticks(5);
    };

    var make_y_axis = function() {
        return d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left")
            .ticks(5);
    };

</script>
```

Problem here being that the zooming / panning does not interact with my lines. The just stay the same, 'below' the zoomable / pannable grid. Also, one of the lines disappear when trying to zoom / pan and my console says the following:
`Error: Problem parsing d=""` - referring to the following snippet, last line:

```
function zoomed() {
    svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
    svg.select(".x.grid")
        .call(make_x_axis()
            .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat(""));
    svg.select(".y.grid")
        .call(make_y_axis()
            .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat(""));
    svg.select(".line")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line);
};
```

Here's the content of my json result from the controller:

```
[{"Weight":0.0,"Speed":59.9,"Depth":362.24000,"Time":"2014-04-09T10:01:23","Id":0},{"Weight":10.0,"Speed":59.9,"Depth":394.07000,"Time":"2014-04-09T10:01:56","Id":1},{"Weight":971.0,"Speed":70.1,"Depth":425.84650,"Time":"2014-04-09T10:02:28","Id":2},{"Weight":0.0,"Speed":-29.9,"Depth":422.07465,"Time":"2014-04-09T10:03:00","Id":3},{"Weight":1321.0,"Speed":-21.6,"Depth":406.32840,"Time":"2014-04-09T10:03:32","Id":4},{"Weight":-6.0,"Speed":-30.0,"Depth":390.57880,"Time":"2014-04-09T10:04:04","Id":5},{"Weight":3.0,"Speed":59.9,"Depth":404.50380,"Time":"2014-04-09T10:04:36","Id":6},{"Weight":609.0,"Speed":59.9,"Depth":435.79380,"Time":"2014-04-09T10:05:08","Id":7},{"Weight":1.0,"Speed":59.9,"Depth":467.95280,"Time":"2014-04-09T10:05:40","Id":8},{"Weight":-2149.0,"Speed":34.6,"Depth":498.61060,"Time":"2014-04-09T10:06:12","Id":9},{"Weight":2.0,"Speed":59.9,"Depth":529.83060,"Time":"2014-04-09T10:06:44","Id":10}]
```

Trend looks like this in my view now, but the actual lines don't zoom or pan. Only the overlaying grid (black lines) does;
[image]

For simplicitys sake, I've considered just starting over, following the original example found [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3892919), but I really struggle with placing json-loaded data into this.
Hopefully, someone can help me figure this out :)

Comment: You would need to do `svg.selectAll(".line")` to get all of them. Not sure why you're getting a parse error though.

Comment: All my lines seems to disappear when doing that :(

Comment: Hang on, you're using different functions to set the `d` attribute. Try `svg.selectAll(".line").attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); });` in the `zoomed` function.

Comment: No luck. Possibility of a skype session or chat? :)

Comment: Well, it would help if you could provide a complete example.

Comment: Hang on. I'll see if I can return the json publicly.

Comment: A bit hard to get this up and running. Updated my question with how my json looks when it comes from my controller.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't even figure out how to make it work in the first place: http://jsfiddle.net/GkfUz/

Comment: Thanks. Added an image of how it looks when I run it locally. Also added all the data in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nwinger/GkfUz/2/

Comment: You have to assign the scales to the zoom behaviour after setting the domains (or move the definition of the zoom): http://jsfiddle.net/GkfUz/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Lars, I was finally able to solve this. Ultimately, I had to do some changes to my controller in addition to using [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GkfUz/3) which assigns the scales to the zoom behaviour after setting the domains, so it returns a json string to my view like this:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Trend.ToArray());

return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This was due to the fact that some errors appeared when zooming / panning on the array returned without being serialized before returned to the view.

Also had to do the following for it to work:

```
d3.json('@Url.Action("DataBlob", "Trend", new {id = Model.Unit.UnitId, runId = 5})', function(error, tmparray) {
    var json = JSON.parse(tmparray);
    ...
    )};
```

If this step is skipped, my data will not be displayed properly for some reason, being squeezed to the left side of my graph.